# jQuery Flot with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, flot

I was dealing today with Flot and when I try to get the data from PHP (with `json_encode()`) I can't get it work properly.

I could display labels but no chart is created.

#### PHP

```
    $newData = array();

    $newData[0] = array();
    $newData[1] = array();
    $newData[2] = array();

    $newData[0]['label'] = 'Slice 1';
    $newData[1]['label'] = 'Slice 2';
    $newData[2]['label'] = 'Slice 3';

    $newData[0]['color'] = '#122b45';
    $newData[1]['color'] = '#064792';
    $newData[2]['color'] = '#9e253b';

    $newData[0]['data'] = array();
    $newData[0]['data'][0] = 1;
    $newData[0]['data'][1] = 1000;
    $newData[1]['data'] = array();
    $newData[1]['data'][0] = 1;
    $newData[1]['data'][1] = 500;
    $newData[2]['data'] = array();
    $newData[2]['data'][0] = 1;
    $newData[2]['data'][1] = 100;

    echo json_encode($newData);
```

#### jQuery

```
$.ajax({
            url: "get-stats.php",
            type: "POST", 
            async: false,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            data: {section:  section, endDate: endDate, startDate: startDate},
            success: function(data){
                $.plot($("#flot"), data,{
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?
Labels and colors are ok but it seems I can't get the data.

Thank you for your time and concern in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and solution. I had to do following for the data;

```
$newData[0]['data'] = array(array(1,100));
```

This saved my day.